# Using patch to to mock a function (as opposed to a method)

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I want to do something like the following example (found [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html))

```
>>> with patch.object(ProductionClass, 'method', return_value=None) as mock_method:
...     thing = ProductionClass()
...     thing.method(1, 2, 3)
```

However this is patching the method called `method` on `ProductionClass`.  I want to patch a generic function within a context.  Ideally something looking like...

```
with path.something(my_fn, return_value=my_return) as mock_function:
    do_some_other_fn()
```

`my_fn` is called deep within `do_some_other_fn` and therefore is difficult to mock out directly.  This seems like it should be straight forward but I can't find the right syntax

**EDIT**  In the module that `do_some_other_fn` lives I import `my_fn` like followings

```
from my_module import my_fn
```

So I need a way to be able to tell mock to patch that from outside the module.  Is this possible?

**EDIT 2** I think this makes it more clear what I am looking for

This works but is not ideal:

```
import my_module
with patch('my_module.fn', return_value='hello') as patch_context:
    x = my_module.fn()
    # x now contains 'hello'
```

However I would much rather have it work like this (or something similar)

```
from my_module import fn
with patch('my_module.fn', return_value='hello') as patch_context:
    x = fn()
    # x contains real result from real call to fn()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your attempt to patch with `from my_module import fn` does not work because the import statement creates a local symbol `fn` which points to whatever value `fn` has in `my_module` *at the time of import*. You later patch `my_module.fn` but it does not matter because you already have a local copy of `fn`.

If the file that contains the `patch` call is the main module (the file that `python` initially loaded), you should be able to do it by patching `__main__.fn`:

```
from my_module import fn
with patch('__main__.fn', return_value='hello') as patch_context:
    x = fn()
```

If the file that contains the `patch` call is loaded as a module from the main module then `__main__` won't work and you need to pass the absolute module name of the module that contains your `patch` call to `patch` rather than `__main__`.

Answer (score 0):

You can see function like module object's static method. To patch a function  `func` in module `mymodule` you can use

```
patch("mymodule.func", return_value=my_return)
```

You should take care of [Where to patch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch) and if the function is in the same module where you have the test should use `"__main__.func"` as patch argument.

`patch` like `patch.object` can be useed as decorator, context or by `start()` and `stop()` method.

Now when in a module you import a function from an other module like:

```
from mymodule import func as foo
```

You create a new reference to `func` in the new module called `foo`. *Every 
time in this module you call `foo` you will use the reference to `mymodule.func` that you load when you imported it: if you whould like change this behavior you should patch `foo` in the new module.*

To make it more clear I build an example where you have `mymodule` that contain `func`, `module_a` that include `mymodule` and use `mymodule.func`, `module_b` that use `from mymodule import func as foo` and use bot `foo` and `mymodule.func`

`mymodule.py`

```
def func():
    return "orig"
```

`module_a.py`

```
import mymodule

def a():
    return mymodule.func()
```

`module_b.py`

```
from mymodule import func as foo
import mymodule

def b_foo():
    return foo()

def b():
    return mymodule.func()
```

`test.py`

```
import unittest
from unittest.mock import *
import mymodule
import module_a
import module_b

class Test(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_direct(self):
        self.assertEqual(mymodule.func(), "orig")
        with patch("mymodule.func", return_value="patched"):
            self.assertEqual(mymodule.func(), "patched")

    def test_module_a(self):
        self.assertEqual(module_a.a(), "orig")
        with patch("mymodule.func", return_value="patched"):
            self.assertEqual(module_a.a(), "patched")

    def test_module_b(self):
        self.assertEqual(module_b.b(), "orig")
        with patch("mymodule.func", return_value="patched"):
            self.assertEqual(module_b.b(), "patched")
            self.assertEqual(module_b.b_foo(), "orig")
        with patch("module_b.foo", return_value="patched"):
            self.assertEqual(module_b.b(), "orig")
            self.assertEqual(module_b.b_foo(), "patched")    


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

In other words what really rules on choosing where to patch is how the function is referenced where **you want use the patched version**.

Comment: Question about this answer.  If use `patch('mymodule.func'....)` but deep within my code I import with `from mymodule import func` then call `func()`, will it still be patch appropriately?

Comment: Just did some tests and it doesn't look like it works well that way.  If I do `mymodule.func` the patch works fine, but I can't use `from mymodule import func`.  I've updated the question to make this more clear

Comment: @sedavidw as I pointed out clearly in my answer you should take a look to https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch .